# Click an anchor tag in vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net

Please suggest a method in vb.net to perform 'onclick' event on clicking the image in anchor tag.

```
<td style="border: 0px solid white; border-image: none;">

   <div id="clickAnImage100">

   <a onclick="GetMyWebsite('http://www.google.com');" href="#!">
   <img height="34" src="../images/WebClick.png">
   </a>

</div> </td>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Your question is a bit too vague. What kind of `onclick` event are you talking about? A client-side javascript function, or a code-behind function? Where is `GetMyWebsite` defined? Is your `onclick` your attempt, or is this currently working and you *also* want a server-side call made?

Comment: I just need something that will execute the function within the onclick event..something like getElementByTageName("a").click

Comment: What is wrong with what you currently have? If you specifically want it on the `<img>`, just add an `onclick` just as you have with your `<a>`

Comment: Thanks Tyler. But what I need is just to click on the anchor tag programmatically using VB.net to trigger the onclick event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any of your **JavaScript file**, you can simply do that by

```
$( "img" ).click(function() {
  //your logic
});
```

**--OR--**

give a class to your image say `trigger`

```
<a onclick="GetMyWebsite('http://www.google.com');" href="#!">
   <img height="34" src="../images/WebClick.png" class="trigger">
</a>
```

& then in your JavaScript file you can

```
$( ".trigger" ).click(function() {
  //your logic
});
```

If you're looking to "programmatically" call a click inside the onclick event, then what you need is **`trigger()`** method of jquery. This function "fakes" a click event on an element. Can be used like:

```
function GetMyWebsite(link_passed) {
  $(".first").attr("href", link_passed);
  $( ".second" ).trigger( "click" );
  //your logic
}

$( ".second" ).click(function() {
  alert('You called me from first');
});
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/wzrVBE) I created to show you the same. Also the explanation to [tigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method from JQueryAPI.

**Updated answer as you need VB.net way of getting this done.**

In VB.net, all you need is `PerformClick()` method like so:

> Obviously you need to replace the **Button2** to your desired Control(anchor tag control) which you want to click

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'do stuff
    Me.Button2.PerformClick()
End Sub
```

This is just an example of `PerformClick()`, you can call it wherever you want to & perform a click on the anchor tag

Comment: Thanks for the logic. But what I need is just to click on the anchor tag programmatically in VB.net to execute the function within the onclick event.

Comment: Ok, I guess I know what you're looking for. Check my answer for the update added.

Comment: Hi Nikhil, sorry to trouble you again. The anchor tag is in website that I cannot modify. I just need some webpage automation.. I need to click that anchor tag to execute any event associated with it.   To be clear, I just need the VB.net code to click the anchor tag programmatically. Thanks for your wonderful effort.

Comment: Yes, can you check the answer and let me know if that's close to what you had intended ?

Comment: I cannot modify anything in the webpage or html content. As provided, the anchor tag does not have a class or id tag which i can refer. <br> I just need to code in VB.net which will make a click on anchor tag programmatically and GetMyWebsite(..) function will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

For JavaScript

> ```
> <img onclick="javascript:execute_img()" src="../images/WebClick.png" />
> <script>
> function execute_img() {
>      alert("This is execute_img function.");
>  }
> </script>
> ```

For Vb.Net (WebForm):

If you want to get an event use toolbox. Drag and drop PictureBox Control. Click on picturebox chose click event.

Comment: Please refrain from posting code-only answers. Add some description so that future readers also understand what you're doing.